# Is there a Legend Limiter in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend

Is there in QGIS a function or a plugin that works similar to Legend Limiter in ArcGIS? The attribute I want to show in my legend has many possible values, I want my legend to only show those values that are visible on my view in the print composer.

Comment: There is the option "show only visible features" for the table of attributes (in the composer), but it seems there isn't for the legend. The suggestion make sense, so please file a feature request here http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Answer (score 1):

I only know a manual solution for this problem, not an automatic one like Legend Limiter:

You can delete unwanted values from your legend by opening its item properties. Then go to "Legend Items", open the nested legend items shown and select the ones you want to delete. To delete the selected items, click on the green minus-symbol below (btw, you can also rename, group and resort you legend here).

But this would only be feasible if you don't have to weed out dozens of unwanted values for each layer...

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not implemented yet, but there is an open ticket which you can follow http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3121