# QGIS 2.0 have a Legend Limiter feature?

Tags: qgis, legend

I found this old post (concerning QGIS 1.x) [Is there a Legend Limiter in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31605/is-ther-a-legend-limiter-in-qgis) 
and was wondering whether this had been solved in QGIS 2.0. Is there a way of only showing the attributes in the legend that are visible on the map?

It seems to me that this is not straightforward in ArcGIS either and I think it would make sense to impement this (in QGIS as I'm trying to use ArcGIS as little as possible). Imagine how useful it would be when you have a geology maps and you don't want to show hundreds of formation but only the few formations you can actually see in the map composer ...

Comment: Dynamic legends are straightforward in ArcGIS for Desktop but only since 10.1.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I think it's more useful for future reference to have only one version of this question.

Comment: I do apologise but I couldn't find references to Legend LImiter in version 2.0. THat is why i reference the same question regarding version 1.x. I just wanted to see if things had been updated with the recent release of 2.0.

Comment: Don't worry, I linked the corresponding feature request in an answer to the previous question. You can follow the request and you will get an update if it's status changes.